# Get ID from mySQL and set localstorage in ajax with php

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, local-storage

I have this working to a point, but would like, after true is returned, to set localstorage to value of the id passed in mySQL query.  I'm unsure how to pass this, as my php currently echos only true or false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginButton').click(function(){

            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                cache: false,
                data: { username: username, password: password },
                success: function(res) {
                    switch(res) {
                        case ('true'):
                            alert('true');
                            break;
                        case ('false'):
                            alert('false');
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            return false;

        });

    });

</script>


<?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
    $stmt->bindValue('username', $username);
    $stmt->bindValue('password', $password);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)  {
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        }    
    } 
}

$conn = null; 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to respond with several values when using AJAX you may use JSON.

In php code it should be like this (paste it after `$stmt->execute();` line instead of `if-else` construction):

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
  echo json_encode(array('success' => false));
} else {
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];

  echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => true,
    'user_id' => $user_id
  ));
}
```

Then in javascript you should specify that you expect JSON as a response. This is a code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "login.php",
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',    //this is where we specify JSON response
  data: { username: username, password: password },
  success: function(res) {
    if (res.success) {
      localStorage.setItem('user_id', res.user_id);  //set user id to local storage
      alert(res.user_id);
    } else {
      alert('false');
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    //this will trigger in case the server send invalid JSON (or other types of errors)
    alert('false');
  }
});
```

I would also recommend to use GET method instead of POST in this case. POST is usually used when you need to change something of a server (database, session, file system, etc.), but when you want just get some data, it's better to use GET. However no one restricts you to do as you want, but I think it better to follow standard.

Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic, that worked great for me.  I take on board the POST v GET.